# Why does collect fail with "error: value collect is not a member of Int" on the result of reduce?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to find the line with the most no of words using apache spark/scala. I am running the program in spark-shell.

I get the correct output when I use following code:

```
scala> file1.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)
```

But I get error when I try to collect the result using following code:

```
scala> file1.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b).collect()
<console>:30: error: value collect is not a member of Int
              file1.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b).collect()
```

Why is that I get error when I use `collect()` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[reduce](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@reduce(f:(T,T)=%3ET):T) is an action that reduces a series of values of type `T` into a single value of type `T`.

> **reduce(f: (T, T) ⇒ T): T** Reduces the elements of this RDD using the specified commutative and associative binary operator.

After `reduce` you have the final result (that you could have also `collect`ed for other transformations).

In your case, assign the value of `reduce` and check its type. It is `Int`.

```
val result = file1.
  map(line => line.split(" ").size).
  reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)
// check the type of the value from `reduce`
scala> :type result
Int
```

---

`reduce` is very similar to `collect` as both are actions that give you a value, but collect will give you an `Array[T]`...

> **collect(): Array[T]** Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.

...while `reduce` just a single value `T`.